# nginx: problem configuring a proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm converting a web app from apache to nginx.
In apache's httpd.conf I have:

```
ProxyPass /proxy/ http://
ProxyPassReverse /proxy/ http://
```

The idea is the client send this url:

```
http://web-server-domain/proxy/login-server-addr/loginUrl.php?user=xxx&pass=yyy
```

and the web server calls:

```
http://login-server-addr/loginUrl.php?user=xxx&pass=yyy
```

My nginx.conf is attached below and it is not working. At the moment it looks like it is calling the server, but returning an application error. 
This seems promising but any attempt to debug this failed!
I can't trace any of the calls as nginx refuses to place them in the error file.
Also, placing echo statement on the login server did not help either which is weird.

The nginx documentation isn't very helpful about this.

Any suggestion on how to configure a proxy_pass?

Thanks!

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

#
# The default server
#
server {
     rewrite_log on;

    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

#root /var/www/live/html;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;

   location ~ ^/proxy/(.*$) {
#location /proxy/ {
#   rewrite ^/proxy(.*) http://$1 break;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;
          proxy_pass http://$1;
    #proxy_pass "http://173.231.134.36/messages_2.7.0/loginUser.php?userID=ofer.fly%40gmail.com&password=y4HTD93vrshMNcy2Qr5ka7ia0xcaa389f4885f59c9";
    break;
   }

   location / {
    root /var/www/live/html;

    #if ( $uri ~ ^/proxy/(.*) ) {
        #   proxy_pass http://$1;
    #   break;
        #}

    #try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    #location = /404.html {
    #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name; 
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/live/html$fastcgi_script_name; 
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

# Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

}

Comment: It sounds like you want a forward proxy and not a reverse proxy. Nginx might not be best suited for what you want to do.

Comment: @Martin F: What makes you say that?

Comment: @Ofer Bar, have you tried to set log verbosity to debug? The configuration string for that is `error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  debug;`. Could you please attach a debug output to your question?

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for replying. Just to clarify, I'm not trying to find the best tool to do that.
The reason why I am testing nginx instead of apache is that with apache servers we're experiencing lots of servicing errors when getting images, SWF files, etc. We got a recommendation to switch to nginx because it might solve our problems, that's the purpose of the test. BTW, using debug flag doesn't work, no new info is written to the error log. I've read somewhere that nginx needs to be compiled with debug enabled for that to work. Based on the responses here, I guess I'll need to change m

Comment: @womble: it seems he wants the client to tell the server which address to proxy him to, that's a standard forward proxy. Nginx was designed to be a reverse proxy and makes no attempt to be a forward proxy. While it can work in some situations it's often not optimal and can cause extra headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tried this on my nginx testbed and got the following in the log:

```
2011/08/29 22:35:31 [error] 10074#0: *1257 no host in upstream "", client: 10.103.0.9, server: localhost, request: "GET /proxy/ya.ru HTTP/1.1", host: "10.110.0.42"
```

So, nginx is just not a right tool to do that, upstream hosts can't be defined at runtime.

Comment: They can, you just need to host your own DNS server and configure nginx to use it.